# synergy2 replacement

Tags: ubuntu, centos, windows-7, keyboard-video-mouse

Anyone know of a good replacement for Synergy2 that is cross platform and open source? I've been looking around since I upgraded to Win7 which Synergy2 doesn't play well with - which doesn't surprise me since it doesn't look like there has been active development since 2006.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [Synergy](http://symless.com/synergy) which is in active development.

Comment: Ahha! That's exactally it. My 4 monitor 2 machine dream can stay alive! Thanks

Comment: Alas, the "synergy-plus" project, and the previously-open-source "synergy-foss.org" project, has moved to "http://symless.com/synergy/" where it is now a commercial product ($19 or 29).
However, **v1.4.15 of the free download is still available** from the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20140127214348/http://synergy-foss.org/download/?list

Answer (score 0):

You could try Input Director - http://www.inputdirector.com/

However, it only supports Windows.